# How to create link preview in TextFormField like WhatsApp screen, using flutter link previewer?

Tags: flutter

Above I given same type how to create in textform field in Flutter. Iam trying flutter link previewer package. It's not working.

Preview title,image, description how to get.

[image]

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To create the Widget you want, install [any_link_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/any_link_preview/install)

Detect URL link on the text field like this

```
List<String> findUrls(String text) {
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(
    r'https?://(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)+\S*|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)+\S*',    caseSensitive: false,
    multiLine: false,
  );

  Iterable<Match> matches = regExp.allMatches(text);

  if (matches.isNotEmpty) {
    List<String> urls = matches.map((match) => match.group(0)!).toList();
    return urls;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Then put the Link preview on top like this.

```
  AnyLinkPreview(
                      link:'your_url',
                      //  displayDirection: 
                      UIDirection.uiDirectionHorizontal,
                      cache: Duration(hours: 1),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                      // Widget to display when there's an error fetching 
                       preview
                      errorWidget: Container(
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        child: Text('Bad Url!'),
                      ),
                    )
```

Here is the full code for the link preview, you can customize it as you need.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:any_link_preview/any_link_preview.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as devtools show log;


void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late final TextEditingController _controller;
  List<String> urlList = [];
  bool shouldShoLink = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Visibility(
              visible: urlList.isNotEmpty && shouldShoLink,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 110,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [

                    AnyLinkPreview(
                      link:
                      urlList.isEmpty?'': urlList[0],
                      //  displayDirection: UIDirection.uiDirectionHorizontal,
                      cache: Duration(hours: 1),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                      // Widget to display when there's an error fetching preview
                      errorWidget: Container(
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        child: Text('Bad Url!'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 5,
                      right: 5,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            shouldShoLink = false;
                            urlList.clear();
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 25,
                          width: 25,
                          decoration:const BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Icon(Icons.close),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  urlList = findUrls(value);
                });

              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//

List<String> findUrls(String text) {
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(
    r'https?://(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)+\S*|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)+\S*',    caseSensitive: false,
    multiLine: false,
  );

  Iterable<Match> matches = regExp.allMatches(text);

  if (matches.isNotEmpty) {
    List<String> urls = matches.map((match) => match.group(0)!).toList();
    return urls;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```